# Python create a nested structure out of a flat dict with "parent" key

Tags: python, oop, recursion

Let's consider this example in Python 3:

```py
class SimpleObj:
    def __init__(self, own_id: int, parent_id: int):
        self.parent_id = parent_id
        self.own_id = own_id
        self.children_objects = []  # type: List[SimpleObj]

test_dict = {}
test_dict[0] = SimpleObj(own_id=0, parent_id=-1)  # -1 will mean root node
test_dict[1] = SimpleObj(own_id=1, parent_id=0)
test_dict[123] = SimpleObj(own_id=123, parent_id=1)
test_dict[5] = SimpleObj(own_id=5, parent_id=123)
```

What would be the most pythonic way to create a recursive, nested structure where for example SimpleObj with `own_id=1` would have its `children_objects` list filled with one element which would be SimpleObj with `own_id=123`?
It smells so similar to binary tree problem but I really didn't manage to find a working solution to turn this kind of dictionary into a tree-like objects' structure.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can create a small function to handle the creation of a new SimpleObj :

```
class SimpleObj:
    def __init__(self, own_id: int, parent_id: int):
        self.parent_id = parent_id
        self.own_id = own_id
        self.children_objects = []


def addSimpleObj(struct, own_id, parent_id):
    struct[own_id] = SimpleObj(own_id=own_id, parent_id=parent_id)
    if parent_id != -1:
        try:
            struct[parent_id].children_objects.append(struct[own_id])
        except IndexError:
            print('the parent_id does not exists')

test_dict = {}
addSimpleObj(test_dict, 0, -1)
addSimpleObj(test_dict, 1, 0)
addSimpleObj(test_dict, 123, 1)
addSimpleObj(test_dict, 5, 123)
```

It's just a start but it seems to do the trick. You could modify it to handle, for example, the case where you try to recreate a SimpleObj for a key which already exists.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like something that could be useful, I'll try it! I also thought of using a classmethod to spawn new objects and keep track of them.

Comment: I analysed this solution and this does not go recursively. If the structure is nested more than one level this will not work, right?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around I came up with my own solution. There were two main problems to overcome - recursion and dealing with nodes that refer to not-yet-present parents. Here is my solution. It tries to assign objects to their parents recursively and if it fails, it creates a list of orphans. Than, it iterates over orphaned nodes list until all of them are in place. I tested this on multiple configs and it looks like it always works (provided that the input is correct meaning no repetitions or cyclic references etc).

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List


class SimpleObj:
    def __init__(self, parent_id: int, own_id: int):
        self.own_id = own_id
        self.parent_id = parent_id
        self.children_objects = []  # type: List[SimpleObj]

    def assign_to_children(self, what_to_assign: SimpleObj):
        if what_to_assign.parent_id == self.own_id:
            self.children_objects.append(what_to_assign)
            return True
        else:
            for child in self.children_objects:
                if child.assign_to_children(what_to_assign=what_to_assign):
                    return True

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ID: {self.own_id}, PARENT: {self.parent_id}"

test_objects_list = [SimpleObj(own_id=69, parent_id=70),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=59, parent_id=71),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=70, parent_id=71),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=71, parent_id=1),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=1, parent_id=0),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=2, parent_id=1),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=44, parent_id=1),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=6, parent_id=44),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=14, parent_id=10),
                     SimpleObj(own_id=10, parent_id=1)]

def create_tree_from_list_of_obj(list_in: List[SimpleObj]):
    # find root
    root = [obj for obj in list_in if obj.parent_id == 0][0]
    list_in.remove(root)
    print(root)

    orphans = []
    # do the actual work
    for obj in list_in:
        found = root.assign_to_children(obj)
        print(f"Found {obj.own_id}") if found else print(f"Not found {obj.own_id}")
        if not found:
            orphans.append(obj)
            print(f"Adding orphaned node with id {obj.own_id}")

    while orphans:
        print(f"\nTrying to fill in {len(orphans)} orphaned nodes...")
        for orphaned_node in orphans[:]:
            found = root.assign_to_children(orphaned_node)
            if found:
                print(f"Found {orphaned_node.own_id}")
                orphans.remove(orphaned_node)
            else:
                print(f"Not found {orphaned_node.own_id}")
    return root

tree = create_tree_from_list_of_obj(test_objects_list)
```